# Center align TextView in android layout

Tags: android, layout

This is what I'm trying to achieve and I'm just not getting it.

```
 This is a long lable: {image1}{image1}
          Short label: {image1}{image1}
   Other label length: {image1}{image1}
```

Notice that the colons at the ends of the labels are aligned and the images, which are the same dimensions, will also be aligned. The labels of varying lengths will not be left aligned. The labels in reality are all just one word, so space should be be an issue, but the words are not the same widths.

The layout below centers everything but they come out like this.

```
      This is a long lable: {image1}{image1}
          Short label: {image1}{image1}
       Other label length: {image1}{image1}
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout_one">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="@string/image_one"
        android:id="@+id/one"/>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/digit_border"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/one1"
        android:src="@drawable/five"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>        
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/digit_border"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/one2"
        android:src="@drawable/five"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout_days"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_two"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="@string/image_two"
        android:id="@+id/two"/>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/digit_border"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/two1"
        android:src="@drawable/five"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/digit_border"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/two2"
        android:src="@drawable/five"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout_three"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_days"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="@string/image_three"
        android:id="@+id/three"/>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/digit_border"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/three1"
        android:src="@drawable/five"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/digit_border"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/hour2"
        android:src="@drawable/three2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why don't you use `RelativeLayout`

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" in all linear layout, and set gravity to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the weight to your textView and set the gravity to right that way they will take same space for all three rows and gravity right will make sure text is right aligned. Below are the layout files you can set the weight as it works in your case.

> First XML which has basic layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="text1 : "
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/one1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/one2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> Second XML which create full view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_one"
        layout="@layout/test_item" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_two"
        layout="@layout/test_item" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_three"
        layout="@layout/test_item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I thought of using tableviews. Put labels in one table and images in another. Set layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1" for all tables and rows and gravity="right" for all textviews. In linear view spacing is great but tables are one on top of the other. In relative view they are side by side, but the space is different between labels and images, so labels don't line up.

Comment: Nicely done. I'd never seen the <include> block used. That keeps everything lined up. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept the answer so it will close this.